# Manually add username/password to Saved Password list?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I logged into Mozilla's Bugzilla. I noticed Firefox did not save my password.

How do I manually add my username and password to Firefox's Saved Password list?

Answer (score 92):

If you're a developer with 3 minutes to spare, this is how to do it without installing another add-on.

1. On the login page, Inspect Element the username and password fields and take note of their `name` (or `id`, if no `name` is given) attributes. For example on Khan Academy, that would be `identifier` for the username and `password` for the password.
2. Inspect Element somewhere on the page. Find a small div or so, that's easiest.
3. Right click the element in your inspector and choose `Edit As HTML`.
4. Add the following HTML:

   ```
   <form method=post>
     <input name=identifier>
     <input type=password name=password>
     <input type=submit>
   </form>
   ```

   Replace the names (`identifier` and `password`) with the names from step #1. Note that you should *not* replace `type=password`, only the `name=password` field!
5. Enter your credentials on the page in this form and hit submit. Firefox will now prompt you to save the credentials. The website will probably burp up an error or ignore the request or something, but we don't care about that.

Why does this work? Some sites deliberately do something funny to prevent you saving the password (the browser's remember password feature is often seen as insecure); other sites just have a funny form mangled beyond recognition for Firefox. Adding this simple form makes Firefox detect it and when you enter your credentials, it will prompt you to save them.

Now on the login page, as long as the fields actually have `name` attributes at all I guess (and it probably needs to be wrapped in a `<form>` too, I don't know), Firefox will typically recognize the fields and be able to fill them for you.

Alternatively, it might simply be that the website has `autocomplete=off` set on the field. You can remove this as follows:

1. Launch "Tools > Web Developer > Inspector" and hover your cursor over the form
2. When the `form` element is highlighted, look for the attribute that says `autocomplete='off'` (You may have to scroll up and look for the `form` element in the `Inspector` tab)
3. Double click the attribute and change `off` to `on`
4. Firefox should now ask you to save your username and password

Comment: Adding a fake form.. Brilliant idea :))) Worked.. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your 'identifier' will be 'username'. Form can be inserted mostly in any place of DOM. Nice idea! Thanks!

Comment: Note that if the elements don't have a `name` attribute but only an `id`, you can just copy those - works like a charm!

Comment: @ErwinWessels Thanks for the note! If you think it would be good to add that to the post, feel free to edit!

Comment: Thanks! No plugin currently works in Quantum, but of course, this still works.

Comment: @jpaugh "No plugin currently works in Quantum" yeah that's why I'm still on Firefox 55: in 56+, stuff started breaking and they still haven't implemented the APIs necessary to replace them. Not only didn't they give devs time to replace, they aren't even making it possible a year later.

Comment: I obviously love you now. I have zero HTML dev skills. And I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @Santa Good to hear that it's even doable for non-developers! :D

Comment: This didn't work for me initially.  The reason?  I'd previously told FF not to save the password for the site  :/  So, if you're forgetful like me and this method doesn't work then check if you've told FF not to remember the password for the site.

Comment: You can also find the `form` to which the login inputs belong and submit it. E.g. you can click on an input field with the inspector, and do `$0.form.submit()` (`$0` being the last thing you inspected). This should get FF to prompt you to save the password.

Comment: Soooo great! Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also double click on the Form attribute that says "autocomplete=off" and change it to on.

Comment: @AshwinJayaprakash If there is such an attribute, then yes, that would be the easy solution! Do you want to edit that tip in for the edit bonus, or shall I?

Comment: @Luc I've edited the answer. It's awaiting approval. Thanks

Comment: @AshwinJayaprakash Your account doesn't have [any edits that I can see](https://superuser.com/users/81002/ashwin-jayaprakash?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but yesterday there was an [anonymous edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/919327) which I approved (and then slightly edited after approval). So it's no longer waiting approval :)

Comment: Thanks, that was me :) I forgot to sign in

Comment: This is a really nice, complete answer, but to be honest the two below by cnst and Carolus are much more concise and practical.

Comment: @JamieKitson Thanks for letting me know? :P

Answer (score 6):

Since Firefox 70.0 this is **now a built-in feature** in the password manager (Firefox Lockwise). To access it navigate to the saved password list or type `about:logins` in the address bar; At the bottom left corner click the <kbd>Create New Login</kbd>.

PS: Solution to my specific problem - App Store Connect not saving my credentials - I put `https://appleid.apple.com` as the website address when adding a new login.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify the advice by the top poster, the reason the feature doesn't work on some websites, whilst working on others, is due to the non-standard and/or malicious code used by enterprise websites like Hertz.com.

In the case of Hertz.com, I was able to make Firefox save the password by doing the ***Inspect Element*** on the ***Login*** button, and then doing the ***Edit As HTML*** trick, and changing the `type` of `button` from ***`button`*** to ***`submit`***; without this trick, even the ***Remember Password*** bookmarklet wouldn't work:

```
    -<button type="button" class="primary gblFloatLeft" id="loginBtn">
    +<button type="submit" class="primary gblFloatLeft" id="loginBtn">
                                                Login 
                                            </button>
```

In short, doing ***Inspect Element*** and then ***Edit As HTML*** to fix all the malicious and non-compliant HTML works wonders!

Comment: This worked for me when the top-rated answer by Luc did not.  The site was godaddy.com.  I had to re-type the username in the FF dialog asking me if I wanted to save the password.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I figured I'd throw in my solution anyway.

Since Firefox sometimes fights me on certain websites, the solution I've developed is using another browser such as Chrome and saving the username/password there. Then you can import the login information for the specific website from that other browser.

After you've saved the password in the other browser, you can do the import by following these steps:

1. Going to the website in question and clicking the "(!)" to the left of the URL in
   the address bar.
2. Then click the > button to "Show connection details".
3. Then click the "More Information" button at the bottom of this little dialogue.
4. In this new dialogue, go to the "Security" tab.
5. Click the "View Saved Password" button.
6. In this new dialogue, click the "Import" button, and follow the steps from there.*

*These steps are valid for Firefox version: 62.0.2. I imagine it's similar for other versions, but can't say for sure.

Comment: There is no "Import" button in the saved passwords dialog of Firefox version: 60.6.3esr

Answer (score 1):

when I need to add password to Firefox I use [FEBE Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) to extract my passords to Json file edit it an re import the file again.
 i hop that help.

Comment: doesn't work anymore since the FF Version changed to "Quantum"

Answer (score 1):

**I'm author of [Save my Password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-password/) addon for Firefox that solves this problem.**

It creates dummy input fields on the page where you enter (or update) your credentials and when you click the "Save my Password!" button, Firefox will ask you to save (or update) your password for the page.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-password/

Comment: This is so helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are all creating a lot more work for yourselves than seems necessary.

1. Create a CSV file.
   You can do this with an ordinary text editor: or go into Firefox Options, Security, Passwords, and export your current passwords into a CSV file instead of the default XML file.
   Edit this file with a text editor (or spreadsheet).
2. The beginning of the file should look like this:

   ```
   # Generated by Password Exporter; Export format 1.1; Encrypted: false  
   "hostname","username","password","formSubmitURL","httpRealm","usernameField","passwordField"
   ```

   Edit one of the existing entries to change the data to match the entry you want to add, such as:

   ```
   "http://192.168.0.1","admin","modempassword","","","login","password"
   ```

   The last two entries will probably have to match the field names already on the web page as previously described.  I semi-guessed "login" and "password" when I tried this.
3. Go back into Firefox Options Security and import the CSV file.

You now have a new entry in your password manager. No fiddling around with Add-ons (many of which won't work with the current ESL releases) or adding and possibly messing up HTML.  If you make a mistake in the CSV file the worst that can happen is that Firefox won't import it and you'll have to edit it and fix the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer works but there's no need to create a fake form in most cases. Just inspect the login button and change it's type from "button" to to "submit". Enter your password and hit the button, it will prompt you to save but probably not log you in as it's expecting a vanilla button. Refresh the page to undo your changes, enter your email and voila, it should autofill your password.

Answer (score -1):

More simple solution worked for me. No need to add new form. I just added `<input type=submit>` to original login form and another button appeared. First I pressed new button and FF save password dialog appeared. Second I pressed original button and logged in.

Comment: This should be added as a comment to answer https://superuser.com/a/1084364/395378 but not as a new answer.

Comment: I tried, but can't. "You must have 50 reputation to comment" I'm new here.

Comment: Commenting on other people's posts is a privilege gained from earning reputation - if you haven't earned it yet, try to get comfortable writing answers first. https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Sory, I faced this FF problem and found solution here. Later I found more simple solution and wanted to share, but unfortunatelly couldn't do it in proper way. It's first and probably last thing I wanted to share here. No sense to earn any reputation. I have nothing else to tell.

Answer (score -2):

The best idea is not to depend on the browser's caching of the passwords,
since the mechanism will surely change over time, and there will always be a problem
when moving from one computer to another or when using more than one computer.

It is much safer and easier to use a specialized product that will
keep your passwords safe and available on all computers and for all browsers
and programs.

The best one I have found is [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/), where
the passwords and the contents of all the fields in their containing forms are 
encrypted and saved on their servers.
The encryption is done on your side and using your master password for protection,
so the LastPass website has no idea of what is stored on their own servers.

LastPass integrates with the browser to remember passwords and all the other
fields that you have entered into the form, as sometimes more than just the
password is required (for example the email or user-name).
You may also manually enter this data for websites or programs into the LastPass
repository.

The power of this concept was proven when the LastPass website was hacked. The results were rather minor for the users, as the most that the hackers managed to get were the password hints, as the encrypted passwords themselves were useless to them
without the master password.

Another product is the open-source
[KeePass](https://keepass.info/), which is also very popular among users.